# Adding to URL using QUERY_string

Tags: .htaccess

I searched for this issue but couldn't find the exact solution to my problem.

I'm trying to use QUERY_STRING to find part of a URL and then add this to the end of the redirection URL.

```
domain/?atid=00
domain/page/?atid=00
```

The '?atid=' and 'page' will always be the same but the number will change.

eg.

```
domain/?atid=05 domain/page/?atid=05
domain/?atid=21 domain/page/?atid=21
```

I think that I am on the right track with this but it currently doesn't work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^atid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^atid?$ aff-redirection/?atid=%1
```

Or if I do not actually need to use QUERY_STRING I think I would be able to use something along these lines?

```
RewriteRule ^atid=([0-9]+)/$ page/?atid=$1
```

Any help on this would be great!

Comment: Are you simply trying to add `page/` to the URI when `atid={id}` is requested on the root `/` request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^atid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^$ page/$1 [R=302,QSA,L]
```

if it is working you can change 302 to 301 to make it permanent

Comment: I checked it and it is working. If you try it and it is not, make a comment and i will help you.